# PHP Won't Post Table of Values

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have a table of values in HTML that I want to post. It looks like this:

[image: table of values]

After the user selects all of the relevant teams, I want to save it into a form, combining all the rows into a form like this:

PHP:

```
$numRows = 1;
$startMatchNum = 1;
if(isset($_GET['num'])) {
    $numRows = $_GET["num"];
    $startMatchNum = $_GET["start"];
}
```

JavaScript:

```
                     function getSelectionValue(rowNum, columnNum) {
                        document.cookie = "rowNum=" + rowNum;
                        //FOR EXTERNAL PHP FILE
                        //window.location = "http://example.com/file.php";
                        var id =
                            <?php
                            $index = 0;
                            $row = 0;
                            if ( ! empty( $_COOKIE['rowNum'] ) ) {
                                $row = $_COOKIE['rowNum'];
                            }
                            echo '"'.$values[$index].$row.'"';
                            ?>;
                        var e = document.getElementById(id);
                        var selectedValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                    }

                    function postRefreshPage() {
                        var theForm, newInput1, newInput2, newInput3, newInput4, newInput5, newInput6;
                        var rows = <?php echo $numRows; ?>;
                        var nums1 = new Array(rows);
                        // Start by creating a <form>
                        theForm = document.createElement('form');
                        theForm.action = 'addMatch.php';
                        theForm.method = 'post';
                        // Next create the <input>s in the form and give them names and values
                        newInput1 = document.createElement('input');
                        newInput1.type = 'hidden';
                        newInput1.name = 'blue1Team';
                        newInput1.value = "";
                        for(var i = 0;i < rows;i++) {
                            newInput1.value += getSelectionValue(i, 0);
                            if((i + 1) != rows) {
                                newInput1.value += "|";
                            }
                        }

                        newInput2 = document.createElement('input');
                        newInput2.type = 'hidden';
                        newInput2.name = 'blue2Team';
                        newInput2.value = "";
                        for(var i = 0;i < rows;i++) {
                            newInput2.value += getSelectionValue(i, 1);
                            if((i + 1) != rows) {
                                newInput2.value += "|";
                            }
                        }

                        newInput3 = document.createElement('input');
                        newInput3.type = 'hidden';
                        newInput3.name = 'blue3Team';
                        newInput3.value = "";
                        for(var i = 0;i < rows;i++) {
                            newInput3.value += getSelectionValue(i, 2);
                            if((i + 1) != rows) {
                                newInput3.value += "|";
                            }
                        }

                        newInput4 = document.createElement('input');
                        newInput4.type = 'hidden';
                        newInput4.name = 'red1Team';
                        newInput4.value = "";
                        for(var i = 0;i < rows;i++) {
                            newInput4.value += getSelectionValue(i, 3);
                            if((i + 1) != rows) {
                                newInput4.value += "|";
                            }
                        }

                        newInput5 = document.createElement('input');
                        newInput5.type = 'hidden';
                        newInput5.name = 'red2Team';
                        newInput5.value = "";
                        for(var i = 0;i < rows;i++) {
                            newInput5.value += getSelectionValue(i, 4);
                            if((i + 1) != rows) {
                                newInput5.value += "|";
                            }
                        }

                        newInput6 = document.createElement('input');
                        newInput6.type = 'hidden';
                        newInput6.name = 'red3Team';
                        newInput6.value = "";
                        for(var i = 0;i < rows;i++) {
                            newInput6.value += getSelectionValue(i, 5);
                            if((i + 1) != rows) {
                                newInput6.value += "|";
                            }
                        }
                        // Now put everything together...
                        theForm.appendChild(newInput1);
                        theForm.appendChild(newInput2);
                        theForm.appendChild(newInput3);
                        theForm.appendChild(newInput4);
                        theForm.appendChild(newInput5);
                        theForm.appendChild(newInput6);
                        // ...and it to the DOM...
                        document.getElementById('hidden_form_container').appendChild(theForm);
                        // ...and submit it
                        theForm.submit();
                        location.reload();
                     }
```

Then, after it refreshes, it runs this PHP code:

```
        if($_POST) {
            $blueTeam1 = explode ("|", $_POST['blueTeam1']);
            $blueTeam2 = explode ("|", $_POST['blueTeam2']);
            $blueTeam3 = explode ("|", $_POST['blueTeam3']);
            $redTeam1 = explode ("|", $_POST['redTeam1']);
            $redTeam2 = explode ("|", $_POST['redTeam2']);
            $redTeam3 = explode ("|", $_POST['redTeam3']);
            for($i = 0;i < $numRows;$i++) {
                $matchNumber = $i + 1;
                $query = "INSERT INTO match_info (matchNumber, blueTeam1, blueTeam2, blueTeam3, redTeam1, redTeam2, redTeam3)
                                    VALUES ('$matchNumber','$blueTeam1[$i]','$blueTeam2[$i]','$blueTeam3[$i]','$redTeam1[$i]','$redTeam2[$i]','$redTeam3[$i]')";
                $mysqli->query($query);
            }
        }
```

However, it doesn't seem to be submitting. Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I found the error, but I don't know how to fix it. In the Javascript code, the `getSelectionValue` function returns `undefined`, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove

location.reload();

in getSelectionValue() function, because you submit but in the same time you reload the initial script.

Comment: I tested the `postRefreshPage` function without the `location.reload`, but it still returns `undefined`. Could it be the for loops?

Comment: function getSelectionValue does not seem to return anything. try return selectedvalue.

Comment: Good catch! The function's working now, but it still won't post it.

Comment: Check if id exist in document. Maybe document.getElementById(id) is undefined in getSelectionValue . Did you check in javascript console in browser to see if any error? postRefreshPage function look fine to me if you remove location.reload.

Comment: I made a button to test if `getSelectionValue()` works by importing a certain index, and it works perfectly. Then, I alerted one of the values in the form, and it worked perfectly as well. Maybe there's something wrong with my PHP code. The reason why I have the `location.reload()` in the function is because usually the page refreshes when submitting a regular HTML form, so I thought it would do the same thing. It may be my PHP code, but it looks like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was a variety of issues. First of all, the IDs in my PHP code didn't match the IDs in the JavaScript table. Secondly, my use of cookies to pass JavaScript variables to PHP didn't work, so I copied the PHP array I wanted to access and set it again in JavaScript. So, the function `getSelectionValue(rowNum, columnNum);` doesn't need to access the PHP code. Lastly, my table in the database didn't have the `matchNumber` column in it, so the whole process failed.

Thanks to all those that helped!